# Printing different things on different SSH sessions

Tags: python, ssh

I'm making a TUI card game for a school project, where each player would take turns sitting on the machine to play a card, get up, and let the next player play and so on.

The layout I have for the moment is printing the table (on which you can find all of the previously put cards), then a line of cards in the hand of the player.

What I want to do now is make it properly multiplayer where multiple people can connect on a machine with ssh, start the program,  and have each player see his cards at all times (the only thing changing being the table each time another play puts a card).

My problem is I don't even know where to start to do that. Is there a way to attribute an ID to a terminal, and print certain things but not others ? for example :

```
if (id == SSHid_1) :
    print(CardsPlayer1)

if (id == SSHid_2) :
    print(CardsPlayer2)

if (id == SSHid_3) :
    print(CardsPlayer3)
```

Also, is there a way to prompt input from a specific SSH session?

Answer (score 0):

You may find it convenient to append `(timestamp, cards)` tuples
to files that follow a certain naming scheme:

- /tmp/player1.csv
- /tmp/player2.csv
- /tmp/player3.csv

By convention player1 will *only* write to that first file,
player2 to the 2nd file and so on.

Now, to obtain the state of the game at some timestamp `t`,
we read all rows from all files having stamps `<= t`.

[Stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) each file and read its `mtime`,
the modification time, to learn of new moves.
Consider having all players append to a single file
in order to make fewer stat calls.
Or use one of the more advanced APIs to await events,
such as epoll, poll, or kqueue.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.epoll

---

There are many IPC techniques available.
Using an RDBMS, a redis server,
or a pub-sub service such as kafka
might fit your use case better than
communicating via common FS.